# No Grub menu after Ubuntu 18.04.3 installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 yesterday using a USB, no problems, all went great. The problem is that after reboot the laptop boots instantly into W10, which was pre-installed. Tried to change the bios to legacy from uefi but it doesn't work. I tried EasyBCD but it says that my laptop is booting in EFI mode and it doesn't support it. I also tried EasyUEFI but this doesn't work either. The codes i tried in W10 cmd are : 
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`
I tried the boot repair but it doesn't work either.
I tried the first method from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAwi5rUuSkA&t=332s and after that when I try to boot to legacy it gives me intel undi pxe-2.1 (build 083) error on startup.

Is there something I can do? I can log into ubuntu only with the usb and its not even my installation its the try without installation mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I did it. I opened ubuntu using the USB drive then in the terminal I installed the boot-repair using :

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

Run the program and clicked Recommended repair then I followed the instructions. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Gotta love boot-repair. Glad you got it sorted.